# What can I do if MySQL installer is stuck?

Tags: mysql, installation, download

[here is the image :)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aYFjR.png)

I tried to download mysql files by my sql installer. So I finished downloading things in 'download' section in the image. But when I go out from the page by mistake and come back to the 'download' section, just blank box appears like the image I uploaded. And it doesn't work anymore. What can I do for now? (Fyi, I use Windows OS)

Answer (score 0):

Just look for the **offline** installer, there are two options, pick the bigger one:

- mysql-installer-web-community - 2.4M
- mysql-installer-community - 422.4M

[image: MySQL Download Installer]